# Can't find adequate change of variables $y=u^{\alpha}x^{\beta}$ for this equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm studying for a test on ODEs by running through a bunch of exercises, and this one has me stuck. I'd like to find the general solution to $$xy^{\prime} = \sqrt{y^2+x^6}$$

The hint they give me is to use a substitution $y = u^{\alpha}x^{\beta}$. The first thing I did was (and in this removing $0$ from the domain of $y(x)$, at least for the time being) divide out to get $$y^{\prime} = \sqrt{\frac{y^2+x^6}{x^2}}$$
After some playing around I figured that, for the substitution to be useful, it should change the equation into a separable one, which could happen if, for instance, $y^2/x^2 = u^{2\alpha}x^{2\beta-2}$ were equal to $x^3u^{\gamma}$, so I could take a common factor of $x^{3/2}$, and the other factor would only have terms in $u$. So I tried $y = ux^{5/2}$.

This got me to the expression $$u' = \frac{1}{x^{5/2}}\left(\sqrt{u^3 + x^3}-5x^{3/2}u\right) \Rightarrow \frac{u'}{\sqrt{u^2+1} - 5u} = \frac1x$$
Which in theory can be integrated quite easily. However the LHS is clearly not a simple integral (for humans; a CAS solves it in no time). It can be done with some hyperbolic trig. substitutions, but on the whole it becomes quite ugly. What's more, I'd end up having [complicated expression in u] = $\ln x + k$, and that won't help me find $u$ explicitly, let alone $y$. Then I tried doing the same without a determined value for $\alpha$, to see if a certain value would make the LHS have an easy primitive. This is to say, I let $y=u^{\alpha}x^{5/2}$ and I got: $$\frac{\alpha u'u^{\alpha-1}}{\sqrt{u^{2\alpha}+1} - 5u} = \frac1x$$

However I can't see which value of $\alpha$ will help here.

A couple of things occur to me as "the problem":

a) I'm not calculating right and things actually turn out much simpler.

b) I'm too set on the idea of achieving a separable equation, when maybe I could get linear, Bernoulli, etc.

c) I'm missing something extremely obvious and the only problem is in my head.

Can someone help me solve this?

Comment: are you sure that you have made no typo?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner As far as copying my work to the screen, I'm sure I haven't. As I said, I may have made mistakes in calculations to begin with though. You can at least trust the equation in any case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be $y = u x^{3}$, which makes the separable differential equation
$$ u' = \dfrac{\sqrt{u^2 + 1} - 3 u}{x}$$
This does give you a complicated implicit equation when you integrate.
There's no getting around it: I would not expect an explicit closed-form solution for $y$.

Comment: Ah, ok. I guess I should have admitted that possibility too, thanks.